# Playing a movie before loading the tab bar in the App Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, there's an introductory splash video that plays before the user sees the tab bar view.  Adding the video was a last minute decision on my part, so my app delegate is currently set up to load the tab bar controller first and foremost.

I've tried to minimize the amount of code refactoring needed to have the video load first by adding the following code early in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(splashVideo:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Which goes to this method...

```
- (void)splashVideo:(id)sender {
    url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"splashsmall" withExtension:@"m4v"];
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [homeViewController presentModalViewController:moviePlayerController animated:NO];  
}
```

This works very well, though you can still, on occasion, see the tab bar controller for a split second before the video loads.

My question is: is there a guaranteed way to prevent the tab bar controller from being visible until after the video has played?  Am I going to have to cut up the code in some drastic way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html), your app may be rejected if you show unnecessary loading screens at application launch.

Edit:

Have you tried:

```
tabBarController.view.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually developing the app for a client, who is insistant on the splash screen.  We'll see what Apple does upon submission I suppose.

Comment: Event though FreeAsInBeer is right with his remark about the HIG, it is by now almost common to have an introductional short clip playing when starting the app. From my experience, such app will not get rejected - but maybe I am just lucky.

Comment: Hiding the tabBarController prior to playback... brilliant!  And thanks Till.  If Angry Birds can get away with a post-Default.png splash screen, I think I'll be OK too.